# How to add file (image) path to the command line argument in python

Tags: python, opencv, argparse

**This is the actual code**

```
import argparse
import cv2

    ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i","--image",required=True,help="Enter the path")
    args=vars(ap.parse_args())
    
    image=cv2.imread(args["image"])
    print("The Height is : {}".format(image.shape[0]))
    print("The Width is : {}".format(image.shape[1]))
    print("The Channels is : {}".format(image.shape[2]))
    
    cv2.imshow("image".image)
    cv2.waitkey(10000)
    cv2.imwrite("cat1.jpg",image)
```

**This error appears**

line 1
python3 fetch_display.py -i D:/Wallpaper/cat.jpg
^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**I gave input as :**

```
 python3 fetch_display.py -i D://Wallpaper//cat.jpg
```

Comment: Try and put '--image' first. Also, it's best practice to not have `required` options - try just making your argument `ap.add_argument('image', help='Enter the path')` - your CLI would then be `python3 fetch_display D://Wallpaper//cat.jpg` -- This is all assuming you dont actually have your code indented as you have it in the post (that's a Syntax Error)

Comment: use "\\" or "/", not "//"